# I want to set the column to null depending on three other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
TableA                 TableB               TableC
Col1 ID                Col1 ID              TableA.ID
Col2 NAME              Col2 NAME            TableB.ID
Col3 STATUS
```

And i want to set TableA.Col3 to null if table.c contains TableA.ID and TableB.Id where TableB.Name = "test". Is it possible?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having that table data.

Comment: yes, it's possible. For example, using join between A, C and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
update tablea a
join tablec c on c.tablea_id = a.id
join tableb b on b.id = c.tableb_id
set status = null
where b.name = 'test'
```

Result:

```
id  name    status
--  ------  ------
10  Peter   1     
20  Anne    null  
30  Claire  3
```

The data I used is:

```
create table tablea (
  id int,
  name varchar(10),
  status int
);

create table tableb (
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table tablec (
  tablea_id int,
  tableb_id int
);

insert into tablea (id, name, status) values (10, 'Peter', 1);
insert into tablea (id, name, status) values (20, 'Anne', 2);
insert into tablea (id, name, status) values (30, 'Claire', 3);

insert into tableb (id, name) values (101, 'one');
insert into tableb (id, name) values (102, 'test');

insert into tablec (tablea_id, tableb_id) values (10, 101);
insert into tablec (tablea_id, tableb_id) values (20, 102);
insert into tablec (tablea_id, tableb_id) values (30, 101);
```

Comment: @Fur1at . . . This should not work in MySQL, because `tablea` is being updated and in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Update` using `Join`

```
UPDATE TableA T1 
  JOIN TableB T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
  JOIN TableC T3 on T1.ID = T3.ID
SET T1.STATUS = NULL
WHERE T2.Name = 'test'
```

[**MySQL UPDATE JOIN**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

Comment: I don't think there's a join between Table A and Table B.

Comment: @TheImpaler He mention ID is common between TableA and TableB but i amnot sure between TableA and TableC, that he has to confirm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists` for this purpose:

```
update tablea
    set status = null
where exists (select 1
              from tablec c join
                   tableb b
                   on b.id = c.tableb_id 
              where tablea.id = c.tablea_id and b.name = 'test'
             );
```

This should work in *any* database.  It also gives the optimizer more room to find the best query plan.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do it.

```
    UPDATE tableA as t
    Set Status=NULL from TableA t 
    left join TableC tc on t.ID=tc.tablea_id 
    left join tableb tb on tb.id=tc.tableb_id
    where tc.tablea_id is not null and tb.name='test'
```

Comment: These are just regular JOINs. And your syntax is wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with a regular join? Is your code for special joins only? And as for Syntax, I forgot that MySql likes more words.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with regular joins; just don't pretend they're left joins when they're not! As for syntax, that's also about the order in which the words appear. Gordon's answer is instructive, as is Vignesh's.

Comment: Disclaimer - I work predominantly in TSQL. We like to name our JOINS. These are LEFT JOINS as they retain all the data from the left table each time, and are then filtered by the WHERE clause. So they are not not left joins. MySQL's "join"  is a lazy INNER JOIN, it just happens that in this case it doesn't matter if you go INNER or LEFT. I agree that Gordon and Vignesh had better answers. That doesn't make this one invalid though.

Comment: These are rendered as INNER JOINs, so they're INNER JOINs.